# How can you group consecutive lines in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a file that looks like the following:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
```

I want to reformat it like:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l
m
```

I want the number of columns to be configurable. How would you that with bash? I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
host:~ user$ cat file
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
host:~ user$ xargs -L3 echo < file
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l
m
host:~ user$
```

Replace '3' with how many columns you want.

Comment: My first thought was `sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g' foo`; why didn't I think of using `xargs` for text manipulation?

Comment: That ought to be `-n3`, not? `-L` is `--max-lines`, `-n` is ofr `--max-args`

Comment: The echo is the default action for the xargs, so `xargs -L3 < file` :)

Answer (score 6):

A slightly improved version of the xargs answer would be:

```
xargs -n3 -r < file
```

This way would handle trailing whitespace better and avoid creating a single empty line for no input

Answer (score 4):

Another one:

```
zsh-4.3.11[t]% paste  -d\  - - - < infile
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l
m
```

Or (if you don't care about the final newline):

```
zsh-4.3.11[t]% awk 'ORS = NR % m ? FS : RS' m=3 infile 
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l
m %
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the `<` operator reverses the order of things, I figured out this more intuitive approach:

```
cat file | xargs -n3
```

However, after tests with large files, the `paste` approach turned out to be much faster:

```
cat file | paste -d\ - - -
```

Answer (score 1):

```
column -x -c 30 /tmp/file
a       b       c
d       e       f
g       h       i
j       k       l
m
```

Yes, the spacing isn't exactly what you wanted, but it would handle variable sized inputs "better" (for some definitons of better).